# Debian Squeeze development box cannot connect to the internet, local network does work

Tags: debian-squeeze

Good evening all,

Strange situation: I work from a local development machine running apache and lighttpd in tandem. Today I tried to install curl-php5 which stated that the repository is unreachable.
After further analysis it seems to me that debian cannot connect to the internet ( outside the network ) for some reason.
I do not possess the necessary knowledge to debug this issue any further and have run out of URL's with bash snippets to try. I therefore kindly request your assistance in this matter.

```
dmesg | grep egiga0
egiga0: mac address changed
egiga0: link down
egiga0: started
egiga0: link up, full duplex, speed 1 Gbps
```

The network is routed through a switch that connects several computers and the devbox to the modem where the devbox is assiged 192.168.178.30 statically.

The interface egiga0 has the following properties:

```
ifconfig -a
egiga0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:d6:4d:a6:97:76
          inet addr:192.168.178.30  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:532
          RX bytes:646188 (631.0 KiB)  TX bytes:14662888 (13.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:11
```

As per your request, the output of nano /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.178.1
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

and the output of ip route show:

```
192.168.178.0/24 dev egiga0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.30
224.0.0.0/8 dev egiga0  scope link
default via 192.168.178.1 dev egiga0
```

The machine itself is a d-link sharecenter running the ffp ( fun plug ) debian squeeze.
All servers running on it are accessible from the local network as one should expect, however every external command like wget, or ping www.google.nl result in an unresolvable hostname from which I deduce that the internet itself cannot be accessed.

I'll be happy to provide any information requested in order to solve the problem. Input anyone?

Comment: Could you add the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` file and the output of `ip route show` to your question?

Comment: Add the output of `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`, of `host www.google.com` and of `host www.google.com 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Host is an unrecognized command, the first one works as expected.

Comment: You can use `nslookup` instead of `host`.

Comment: Quite sorry, bash cannot find that command

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8305/discussion-between-mircea-vutcovici-and-digitalis)

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out where the problem is - if it is on the box or in the network. Try pinging your default gateway for starters.

In your configuration: `192.168.178.30 255.255.255.0` that will most likely be `192.168.178.1`. Therefore: `ping 192.168.178.1`

If that responds, most likely the router does not route your traffic. Also, check for iptables rules with `iptables -L -n` to ensure that no rules are blocking traffic.

If you can ping the default gateway - try pinging something on the outside based on IP and not on hostname, e.g. Google nameserver: `ping 8.8.8.8` - does it respond?   If it responds, well then DNS is probably the culprit. You would fix that by editing `/etc/resolv.conf` and inserting functioning nameservers (e.g. `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` which are Google nameservers)

Comment: Ok, 192.168.178.1 is indeed the gateway, and that returns pings

Comment: Also, 8.8.8.8 works, albeit a little bit slower.

Comment: I think the local DNS service on the router is down.

Comment: Any way to test for that?

Comment: @Frands Hansen, Interestingly enough, iptables cannot initialize due to the table filter being non-existent.

Comment: @Digitalis This means that the firewall is disabled and can be ruled out from this investigation.

Comment: @Digitalis The `nslookup`, `host`, and `dig` commands can be used to test the DNS service.

Comment: All of those functions are unavailable I'm afraid. Could the problem be anywhere else in the network?